# Octave windows binaries including classdef

Tags: windows, octave, binaries

Are there any octave default branch binaries for windows available somewhere?

If not, is there a simple way of getting a version including classdef for Linux? *simple*, because usually I do not use Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there are windows builds from default (aka development) available but you may ask on the help mailinglist. (Some users there build windows binaries with MXE from development sources)

If you want to build on GNU/Linux I would suggest Debian or Ubuntu in a VM. It is as easy as installing the dependencies, clone with hg, bootstrap, configure, make... You'll find instructions on the wiki http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems#Compiling_from_source

But always keep in mind that these are development sources which generally aren't suitable for productive use and may break sometime.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I ended up doing it (approximately and skipp'in all the failed attempts).

- Install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
- Create new machine, mount ubuntu image, chose dynamic HDD size (or at least 10 GB)
- Install [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download). If strange mixed color screen appears on first boot:

  - [right] <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
  - [right] <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>
- Open Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

  - If sceen resolution cannot be made larger 640*480:
    `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms`
    `sudo reboot`
- `sudo apt-get install mercurial`
- `hg clone http://www.octave.org/hg/octave -r default`
- `sudo apt-get install gfortran debhelper automake dh-autoreconf texinfo texlive-latex-base texlive-generic-recommended epstool transfig pstoedit libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev gperf libhdf5-serial-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev libfftw3-dev texi2html less libpcre3-dev flex libglpk-dev libsuitesparse-dev gawk ghostscript libcurl4-gnutls-dev libqhull-dev desktop-file-utils libfltk1.3-dev libgl2ps-dev libgraphicsmagick++1-dev libftgl-dev libfontconfig1-dev libqrupdate-dev libarpack2-dev dh-exec libqt4-dev libqscintilla2-dev default-jdk dpkg-dev gnuplot-x11 libbison-dev libxft-dev llvm-3.3` (takes a while)
- `./bootstrap`
- `mkdir builddir`
- `cd builddir`
- `../configure --enable-jit --prefix=/opt/octave3.8 JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.2 CFLAGS="-O2 -march=native" CXXFLAGS="-O2 -march=native"` (no TargetData.h found...)
- `make` (takes half an hour or more)
- `make check` (takes a while, gave a failed assertion)
- `make install`
- `./run-octave`

Comment: Very nice. Some minor issues: You are building default but use prefix octave3.8. This should be version 4.1.0+ to avoid confusion. You are installing llvm-3.3 but then use llvm-config-3.2. Does this work? ./run-octave an be used inside the build dir before "make install". After install "octave" should be sufficient.

Comment: @andy *You are installing llvm-3.3 but then use llvm-config-3.2. Does this work?* it did not. Maybe that was the problem. It could not find `TargetData.h`. I could not even find it myself somewhere in all those llvm*/target/ folders. In the end, it just means no JIT will be available as I understand.

Comment: JIT is experimental and should (in my eyes) only be used if you have large loops which can't be vectorized. Btw, which assertion failed? You'll still find it in your build-dir in test/fntests.log

Comment: @andy sparse.tst .................................................\�: ../../liboctave/array/Array.cc:1609: Array<T> Array<T>::transpose() const [with T = int]: Assertion `ndims () == 2' failed.
panic: Aborted -- stopping myself...
octave exited with signal 6

Comment: Ah okay. This issue is reported here http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?43855 and fixed with this cset http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/rev/06b23f224f52